# Cannot import classes.(something) in Pycharm when that 'something' has already been defined

Tags: python, pycharm

```
import classes.game import bcolors, Person
```

[I have been trying to import game.py on my other file main.py but for some reason Pycharm shows this as unresolved error or something like that. What do I do?](https://github.com/JosephDelgadillo/python_text_rpg/blob/master/game.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type `from classes.game import bcolors, Person`, python will look for a file called classes.game.py, which doesn't exist.

Instead you should do

```
from game import bcolors, Person
```

as you're trying to import from the module 'game.py'.

Comment: Can you help me with my new question I'v just posted as well? I'm stuck again.. LOL